# How to use callback in DIspatch in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was looking at the documentation of redux and there was no callback field in the documentation. But there is callback in setState method. Isn't dispatch method responsible for setState function? How can i have a callback in dispatch method of redux?

Comment: dispatch triggers a reducer action with params and reducer action in turn updates the state object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why React `setState` has callback parameter is that React state updates are asynchronous. It's needed to execute the code that depends on updated state:

```
this.setState(..., () => {
  console.log('state updated');
});
```

This isn't the case for Redux. `dispatch` is synchronous and thus it doesn't make sense to have a callback there. It's expected that an action was dispatched right after `dispatch` was called:

```
dispatch(...);
console.log('store updated');
```

> Isn't dispatch method responsible for setState function?

It isn't. Redux store is an alternative to React component state. It doesn't use `setState` internally.

Answer (score 0):

The dispatch method in redux cannot have a callback.  However, Redux provides you with store.subscribe().

With this function you can add event listeners to the store that will get triggered whenever the state changes, so you can do something like this:

```
const callback = () => {
  //check the store for your specific state change
  //perform some action
}
store.subscribe(callback)
```